# asyncio TaskGroup throwing TypeError when returning lists

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.11

I am trying to use the new TaskGroup object in Python 3.11 to return lists, and I am struggling to find the correct syntax.  There isn't much example code out there yet for this new feature, so I figured I'd ask.

```
import asyncio

async def squares(nums):
    return await [n**2 for n in nums]

async def squares_tasks(nums1, nums2):
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup as tg:
        squares1 = tg.create_task(squares(nums1))
        squares2 = tg.create_task(squares(nums2))
        return squares1, squares2

nums1, nums2 = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
squares1, squares2 = asyncio.run(squares_tasks(nums1, nums2))
```

This throws the following error:
`TypeError: 'type' object does not support the context manager protocol`

I would appreciate any pointers for what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your program. Here is a correct one:

```py
import asyncio


async def squares(nums):
    return [n**2 for n in nums]


async def squares_tasks(nums1, nums2):
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        squares1 = tg.create_task(squares(nums1))
        squares2 = tg.create_task(squares(nums2))

    r1 = squares1.result()
    r2 = squares2.result()

    return r1, r2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums1, nums2 = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
    squares1, squares2 = asyncio.run(squares_tasks(nums1, nums2))
    print(squares1, squares2)
```

First, you must wait for the tasks to finish, that is, you must use `squares1` and `squares2` *outside* of the async-with statement. Second, you must use the `.result()` method to get the actual result of the task.

Please, also note that there is nothing that is async in your `squares` function so you will not get any benefits from using AsyncIO here.

Comment: thank you!!   I appreciate the quick response.  I am very confused why this does not require the use of `await` anywhere?

Comment: There is no `await` in the `squares` function because there is no async operation in it and there is no `await` before `squares1.result()` because you *already* awaited it in the async-with block, thus the result is already available if no error occurred. Take a look at the `TaskGroup` documentation and how the async-with work together to understand why the results are already awaited.